# How to add connect with todo list item component

Tags: redux, react-redux

All:

I am pretty new to redux and react-redux, I wonder if I design a todo item component(the element unit of a todolist) like

```
const todo => ({id, todocontent}) {
    return <li key={id}>{todocontent}</li>
}
```

then how can I build that mapStateToProp function and use it with connect?

Say the todo list data is like :

```
{
    title: "TodoList",
    version:"1.0",
    todolist: [
        {id:"id1", todocontent: "todo 1"},
        {id:"id2", todocontent: "todo 2"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.items.forEach((item) => {
          return <todo id={item.id} todocontent={item.todocontent} />
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    items: state.<yourReducerName>.todolist
  }
}

connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent)
```